# Implementing Finite Differences solver for 2D Poisson Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab, finite-differences, kronecker-product

I'm trying to solve the 2D Poisson equation:

$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = f & \text{in} \hspace{0.2cm} \Omega=(0,1)^{2} \\
g = u  & \text{on} \hspace{0.2cm}\partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$

Using finite differences with order of accuracy 2, by discretizing the square into a mesh with step size $h$ in each direction. I chose $u$ and $f$ such that:

\begin{align*}
u(x,y) &= sin(\pi x) \\
f(x,y) &= \pi^2 sin(\pi x)
\end{align*}

I saw that this could be written as a linear system $A_{h}^{2D} \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{f}$ where $\mathbf{u}$ is the vectorization of the matrix $(U_{h})_{i,j} = (u_{h}(x_{i}, y_{j}))$ and $\mathbf{f}$ is the vectorization of $(F)_{i,j} = (f(x_{i}, y_{j}))$, and:

$$
A_{h}^{2D} = I \otimes A_{h} + A_{h} \otimes I
$$

where $A_{h} = \frac{1}{h^{2}}tridiag(-1,2,-1)$ and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.
The following is my attempt at an implementation, however the actual solution (right) is very far off from the computed one (left) even as I make the step size h very small. I'm wondering if anyone can tell what could be going wrong in the implementation in Octave (MATLAB)? Thanks so much.
[image]

```
clear all
close all

f = @(x,y) (pi^2)*sin(pi*x);
u = @(x,y) sin(pi*x);

N = 20;
h = 1/(N+1);

Ah = (1/(h^2))*(diag(-1*ones(N-1,1),-1) + diag(2*ones(N,1),0) + diag(-1*ones(N-1,1),1));

counter = 1;
for j=h:h:1-h
  for i=h:h:1-h
  F(counter,1) =  f(i,j);
  counter = counter+1;
  endfor
endfor

counter2 = 1;
for j=0:h:1
  for i = 0:h:1
  usol(counter2,1) = u(i,j);
  counter2 = counter2+1;
  endfor
endfor

I = eye(N);

Ah2D = (kron(I,Ah) + kron(Ah,I));

% Computed solution
uh = Ah2D\F;

% Reshaping uh
U = reshape(uh,N,N);

% Now imposing boundary conditions
Utotal = zeros(N+2,N+2);
Utotal(:,1) = u(0:h:1,0);
Utotal(:,N+2) = u(0:h:1,1);
Utotal(1,:) = u(0,0:h:1);
Utotal(N+2,:) = u(1,0:h:1);
Utotal(2:N+1,2:N+1) = U;
Usol = reshape(usol,N+2,N+2);

% Plotting
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:h:1, 0:h:1);
subplot(1,2,1)
surf(X,Y,Utotal)
subplot(1,2,2)
surf(X,Y,Usol)
```

Comment: You are not incorporating the BC into the solution of the problem in the interior, that is why your method is breaking.

Comment: Ohh you're right! Looking back in my class notes, to get the I x Ah + Ah x I we had assumed homogeneous dirichlet boundary conditions, which aren't happening in this case. Would you have any idea how to go about incorporating the boundary conditions?

Comment: In an elegant way like that, I don't immediately see how to do it. Manually, it's straightforward: you have $22^2$ points total, so with zero based indexing you can index $(i,j)$ for $i,j=0,1,\dots,21$ as $22i+j$. Then your equations on the interior relate $(i,j)$ in the interior to $(i \pm 1,j \pm 1)$ (which might be on the boundary), thus row $22i+j$ has nonzero entries in columns $22i+j$ (namely $4/h^2$) as well as $22(i \pm 1) + (j \pm 1)$ (namely $-1/h^2$).

Comment: Then you have the remaining 44 equations for the boundary conditions, which in the way I described it, you would keep explicitly. (You can instead change the interior equations by baking the boundary terms into the RHS of those equations.)